# Should I apply a mixed effects model?

Tags: distributions, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

My goal is to find the effects of properties’  steep slopes on their sales values (after adjusting for inflation).  In order to account for the fixed effects of lot sizes and variations among property's cross dates, I fit the following mode in R using the `nlme` package:

```
fit <- lme(log(sales_value) ~ lotsize_group + SteepSlope,
           random = list(sa_property_id = ~1, sr_date_transfer = ~1), 
           data = final_sea_sf_sv_ss)
```

However, the residual plot shows an increasing pattern in residual values, and the distribution is heavy-tailed (see plots below).  So I am wondering if anyone can tell me how I should fix this model. [The data are available here.](http://huafengzhang.com/2018/03/05/data-for-question-should-i-apply-a-mixed-effects-model/) (You will need to open the link first, then click 'here' to download the data.)

[image: residual plot]

[image: QQ-plot]

Comment: Something seems to have gone dramatically wrong there as the model should have removed any linear pattern from the residuals. Why did you tag this meta-analysis by the way? Are you using multiple primary studies?

Comment: No, I just tagged by accident. (Sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Random effects only work for categorical variables. So you will need to add to account for inflation differently. For example, you could transform the date into just the year and use that as a random effect.

Also, the property ID should not be a included in the model at all since it is confounded with the slope (i.e. the model cannot differentiate weather an a property has a higher value because of it's ID or because it has a higher slope). Perhaps this will fix your residual plots.

Another thing, the lmer package is the more recent random effects package for R. Below is a full guide to mixed effects models using lmer. Although it is uses examples from ecology, it applies just as well to other types of data. 
http://qcbs.ca/wiki/r_workshop6